# Is there a way to make a constantly updating symbolic link between Windows and Mac?

Tags: windows-8, symbolic-link, osx-yosemite

So, my problem is slightly unique.

I'm one of the people who still like playing Minecraft, and I like to use both my MacBook and Windows Laptop to play. Nowadays, I have to keep using an USB to transfer the files back and forth, and it's tedious. I'm new to symbolic links, so I'm worried I'm going to do something wrong.

What I need is this: I want to be able to update the save file on Mac, go to Windows, and see the updated file. This should also work vice versa (but not necessarily simultaneously). Is this possible?

Thanks.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I don't know about on the Mac, but this is possible in Windows.

[Creating Symbolic Links](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/windows/desktop/aa363878(v=vs.85).aspx)

You also may be looking for a [junction point](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/NTFS_junction_point).

Maybe you can use a cloud storage tool like DropBox to synchronize the files, link/junction with to the folder where the synchronized files are stored, and use that as your save path (or whatever you intend to use it for).

Comment: Thanks, this is similar to other answers. I'll try this, and report back if it works.

Answer (score 0):

Here is a possible solution. I haven't tried it though but looks good enough https://stackoverflow.com/questions/21403772/how-to-use-reuse-softlinks-created-on-mac-in-windows-8

Comment: As it’s currently written, your answer is unclear. Please [edit] to add additional details that will help others understand how this addresses the question asked. You can find more information on how to write good answers [in the help center](/help/how-to-answer).